# How to read file by charachter-by-symbol method and put it to array?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a text file, which has many words. They're united by two-three words by ':' and devided from other groups by '.'

There're 100 groups.

For example:

> Programmer:Web-Designer:System
>   Administrator.Biologist:Pharmacist:Chemistry Teacher.

All words before the dot are single group.

My purpose is to add all groups of words to two-dimensional array [10][10] (whole size is 100 elements).

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[][] array = new String[10][10];

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Alexey\\eclipse-workspace\\Plugin\\src\\MatProList.txt"))) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
                while ((char)br.read() != '.') {
                    array[i][c] = array[i][c] + (char)br.read();
                }
            }


            if (br.read() == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What do I wrong here? Please, help.

Comment: Reading the entire file at once and then splitting it by delimiters is a much simpler way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.When you say "what's wrong", what do you mean? What results do you get, AND WHAT RESULTS DO YOU EXPECT?  Why are you summing array[i][c] in the inner loop?

Comment: When I run it, I literally don't get anything. I want to create 'table' 10x10 (array) which would has all groups. Group is the unit of words like Programmer:Web-Designer:System Administrator in my example, i.e it's all before dot. And at the end I want to get array, which would has all 100 groups of words, and I would can get acces to any element of array. When I summing array[i][c] I want to add all symbol which are before '.'

Comment: Why can't you have a one dimensional array instead, String[100], to make it less complex?

Comment: Because in other part of code I want to get from user two coordinates. You can imagine that the first coordinate (if our array has [x][y] indices), x is 'sphere of work' and the second coordinate, y is 'kind of work' and interesction of this coordinates is my element (array[x][y]).

Comment: So the file is sorted into spheres and kinds of work with the first 10 groups making up 10 kinds in one sphere and so on?

Comment: I tried to make picture https://imgur.com/IFHwbSg Don't pay attention on green rectangle. All in the brown rectangle are elements (100), kinds = x [0;9], spheres = y [0;9].

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information. Don't use comments for that. Not all comments will be visible initially. Put everything in one place to make it easy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it even though I prefer to work with a ListArray myself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] groups = new String[10][10];

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile"));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        while (line != null) {
            String[] groupArray = line.split("\\.");
            for (int i = 0; i < groupArray.length; i++) {
                groups[row][column] = groupArray[i];
                column++;
                if (column > 9) {
                    column = 0;
                    row++;
                }
                if (row > 9) {
                    //throw exception or just ignore further groups
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO: handle exception
    } 
}
```

Regarding your code the main problem is your while loop where you read two char but only use one (first in the loop header and then when assigning).

If you want to keep your char by char reading I would change the while loop like this

```
StringBuffer nextGroup = new StringBuffer();
char nextChar = br.read();
while (nextChar != '.' && nextChar != -1) {
    nextGroup.append(nextChar);
    nextChar = br.read();
}
array[i][c] = nextGroup.toString();
```

Comment: I've solved the problem by little different way, but my solution is irrationally, therefore now I'm learning DB structures. Anyway, thank you for the answer. I think that your solution is the most correct for this task.